# How to change font size in word document produced by R Markdown?

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, font-size

Below is a simple example of a R markdown file, from which I want to produce a word document with font size of 10. I went through different solutions proposed in the forum but none worked. It only worked for html file but not word.

```
--- 
title: "Title"
output:
    word_document: 
      number_sections: yes
      df_print: paged
fontsize: 10pt
---
# Section
text
```

Comment: TBMK the answer is: You can't. The font size is set by the Word template, i.e. via the styles. If you want a different font size you have to use/create a custom reference document. That's similar to an HTML document where you have to use a custom CSS to set the font size.

Comment: How do you do that exactly?

Comment: Easy way. Render e.g. an empty Rmd as word document. Then store the resulting word document as e.g. `my-template.docx`. Open in Word and adjust the styles to your liking. Then use `reference_docx: my-template.docx` in the YAML as option of `word_document:`